# Tkinter + RFID, only display images when RFID tag is read

Tags: python, tkinter, rfid

I have to write a program that displays images when RFID tags are located on the RFID reader and removes the images when the RFID tags are removed from the RFID reader.

The following code can display the images when tag or tag 2 are read, but the continue to display them.

```
from Tkinter import *
import serial
import time

one = '0419AC8E70'
two = '0419ACB481'

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400)

reader = ser.read(11)


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()


photo = PhotoImage(file="/home/daniel/Desktop/BY/test3.gif")
photo2 = PhotoImage(file="/home/daniel/Desktop/BY/test2.gif")
firstimage = Label(frame, image=photo)
secondimage = Label(frame, image=photo2)

def set_image():
    if one in reader:    
        print("1")
        ser.flush()
        time.sleep(1)       
        firstimage.pack( fill = BOTH)   
    else:
        firstimage.pack_forget()
    if two in reader:    
        print("1")
        secondimage.pack( fill = BOTH)  
        ser.flush()
        time.sleep(1)   
    else:
        secondimage.pack_forget()

    firstimage.after(200,set_image) #to run set_image function at regular intervals


set_image()
root.mainloop()
```

The thing that disturbs me is the root.mainloop() function from the Tkinter gui. How can I make the program only display the images when the corresponding tag is read and not display anything when not tag is read?

Comment: @akhilc Tkinter doesn't work like that

Comment: Just tried, I am getting stuck the while loop, continuously printing e.g. 1. guess the problem is that the reader variable is not being updated this way

Comment: Is there an event that triggers when a tag is presented? If so can you let me know what the event is and I'll see if I can write the tkinter side of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with this...

```
from Tkinter import *
import serial
import time

one = '0419AC8E70'
two = '0419ACB481'

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400)

reader = ser.read(11)


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()


#photo = PhotoImage(file="/home/daniel/Desktop/BY/test3.gif")
#photo2 = PhotoImage(file="/home/daniel/Desktop/BY/test2.gif")
firstimage = Label(frame)
firstimage.pack()
secondimage = Label(frame)
secondimage.pack()

def set_image():
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2400)
    reader = ser.read(11)
    if one in reader:    
        firstimage.config(text="One in reader")  
    elif two in reader:    
        secondimage.config(text="Two in reader")  
    else:
        firstimage.config(text="One not in reader")
        secondimage.config(text="Two not in reader")

    firstimage.after(2000,set_image)
    secondimage.after(2000,set_image)

set_image()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried using this - added to the question. I get stuck at the first image when the tag is read. The program is stuck in the "if one in reader " statement.

Comment: @Daniel Robotics Try this and see if it works for your setup.